# Closing ResultSet is must or not?

Tags: jdbc

I have written a query as given below-

```
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {

        String fetchOneSQL = "select p.NAME from PAPER p where  p.PAPERID="+paperId;
        dbConnection = icrudResultAnalysis.getConnection();
        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(fetchOneSQL);
        rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            Paper paper=new Paper();                
            paper.setName(rs.getString(NAME));              
        }

        // get new records list
        preparedStatement=null;
        rs=null;

        String getListSql="select ib.NAME from ITEMBANK ib  where ib.ITEMBANKID="+itemBankId;
        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(getListSql);
        rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            ItemBank itemBankObj=new ItemBank();
            itemBankObj.setName(rs.getString(NAME));
            listItemBanks.add(itemBankObj);
        }

        rs.close();
        preparedStatement.close();
        dbConnection.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception Occured while fetching All record: "
                + e.getMessage());
    } finally {

        try{
            if (rs!=null){
                rs.close();
            }
        }catch(SQLException e)
        {
            LOGGER.error(RESULTSETCLOSEEXCEPTION    + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            if (preparedStatement != null) {
                preparedStatement.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error(STATEMENTCLOSEEXCEPTION
                    + e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            if (dbConnection != null) {
                dbConnection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error(CONNECTIONCLOSEEXCEPTION
                    + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

In above code i have used single resultset for two select statement by creating **ResulSet rs =null** . Is it good practice? Or i have to close ResultSet each time? What is difference between closing ResultSet and making ResultSet null?

Comment: What does the javadoc of ResultSet.close() say?

Comment: You should close *any* resource as soon as you're finished with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All resources MUST BE CLOSED after use using `.close()` method! And resultSet is not an exception, except in this case (from [ResultSet javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)):

```
A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.
```

In your case you have to manual `.close()` the first opened resultset, but not necessary the second used; making a `resultSet = null` only set reference to variable `resultSet` equals `null`, no more no less.
If you are using Java7, Resultset is implementing [AutoCloseable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) and you can use this feature to rewrite your code in cleaner way (look [Oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html))

Answer (score 0):

When you are **re-using resources(resultSet,PrepareStatement),they must be closed first**...Instead of setting prepare statement to NULL.You must close it and it will automatically close the result set.There is no need to explicitly close the result set.